# Use NETCore ScopedService outside Controller

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, webapi

First, let me explain breafly what I have, what I want to achieve, how I did it so far, and why I'd like to improve my current implementation.

---

**WHAT I HAVE**

Basically, I have a .NET Core project that runs an API Service with some APIs.
Also, I have a class called `MyFundamentalClass`, which is used throughout the whole application: in fact, `MyFundamentalClass` implements the Singleton Pattern, having something like this:

```
public class MyFundamentalClass {
    private static _myFundamentalClass = null;

    public static MyFundamentalClass GetInstance() {
        if (_myFundamentalClass == null)
            _myFundamentalClass = new MyFundametalClass();

        return _myFundamentalClass;
    }
}
```

Reason why I want this Singleton Pattern is that this class is used in many occasion in the whole project; the alternative would be to instantiate the class in the ControllerAction, and then pass it basically EVERYWHERE: it's not sustainable.

---

**THE PROBLEM**

As you can imagine, here was the first problem: each request MUST HAVE its own instance of `MyFundamentalClass`. As you can imagine, `static` keyword does not work very well with that.

Why I'm telling this: if I want an instance of `MyFundamentalClass` in each ControllerAction, I should write something like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetUserData() {
    MyFundamentalClass = new MyFundamentalClass();
    return await MyFundametalClass.GetUserData();
}
```

So far so good, but as I said, I need the Singleton Pattern, so I should change the code into:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetUserData() {
    MyFundamentalClass = MyFundamentalClass.GetInstance();
    return await MyFundametalClass.GetUserData();
}
```

What's the problem? Two different API calls will overwrite the private field `MyFundamentalClass._myFundamentalClass`, mixing the context of the two API. **HUGE PROBLEM**!

---

**MY CURRENT SOLUTION**

What I found , the only way, was the use of `AsyncLocal<MyFundamentalClass>`. I've something like this:

```
public class RequestContext {
    publicv static AsyncLocal<MyFundamentalClass> Instance = new AsyncLocal<MyFundamentalClass>(null);
}

// Then, in each ControllerAction
public async Task<ActionResult> GetUserData() {
    var method = async () => {
        RequestContext.Instance.Value = new MyFundamentalClass();
        // Whatever I need to do 
    }
}

// Then, in the MyFundamentalClass
public MyFundamentalClass {
    public MyFundamentalClass GetInstance() {
        return RequestContext.Instance.Value;
    }
}
```

With this solution, since the AsyncLocal context lives only thourghout the async context, it perfectly fits my need.
Though, why am I searching for something else? Because I feel like I am missusing the Dependency Injection and the whole ServiceProvider stuffs.

---

**WHAT I AM LOOKING FOR**

So.. I also come upon the `services.AddScoped<MyFundamentalClass>()` code ([Link to Microsfot DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addscoped?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-servicecollectionserviceextensions-addscoped(microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-iservicecollection-system-type))).

By what it tells, it should perfectly fit my need: what is created by that `AddScoped` lives only for the API -> one API one instance.

But, problem is: how could I exploit the instance created by `AddScoped` with the Singleton Pattern?
I know that, with DependencyInject, in my Controller I can add the object in the constructor:

```
public class MyController : ControllerBase {
    private MyFundamentalClass _myFundamentalClass;

    public MyController(MyFundamentalClass myFundamentalClass) {
        _myFundamentalClass = myFundamentalClass;
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> GetUserData() {
        return await _myFundamentalClass.GetUserData();
    }
}
```

That feels much more correct, from a code point of view, but.. I don't have the SingletonPattern anymore, unless I still use the `AsyncContext`.

What I thought it was possible was to use:

```
public static IServiceProvider ServiceProvider;

public static WorkbenchViewModel GetInstance() {
    ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(WorkbenchViewModel));
}
```

But I have the same problem: each request has its own `IServiceProvider`, thus different API would override the value.

Comment: Have you tried using addsingleton https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addsingleton?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-servicecollectionserviceextensions-addsingleton(microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-iservicecollection-system-type)

Comment: Hi! One of the constraint I have is that each request has its own `MyFundamentalClass` instance. `AddSingleton` creates an instance for the whole Server, leading to have the same `MyFundamentalClass` for all the requests. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Short answer - do not use  Singleton Pattern.

Comment: _"But, problem is: how could I exploit the instance created by `AddScoped` with the Singleton Pattern?"_ - why do you wan that? From the description it seems that scoped `MyFundamentalClass` should work. Note that you can (and I would argue) should "bubble up" the DI through the whole application - i.e. other services also should resolve `MyFundamentalClass` as controller does.

Comment: Is Dependency Injection NOT working when you create an instance via `new` keyword?